# Calling a Javascript function from inside a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, function, web

I am trying to use Print.JS to print all PDF files inside of a directory, called uploads. The code below is how far I have got so far, but it isn't working. I would appreciate any solutions or any advice!

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendors/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Resources/css/queries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Resources/css/class.css">
    <title>class1</title>
    <script src="Vendors/js/print.min.js"></script>
</head>

<header>
    <div class="sinclair-header">
        <h1>Class 1 submissions</h1>
    </div>
</header>   


<body>
    <section class="upload-box">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2 box"> 
                    <input type="file" name="file">
                </div>
                <div class="col span-1-of-2 box"> 
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="print">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </section>
</body>

    <?php
    $files = scandir("uploads");
    for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++)
    {
        echo 'printJS('uploads/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>')';
    }
    ?>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is `printJS()` defined?

Comment: You need to wrap your function calls in <script></script> tags if you want to call a JS function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is an external JS script

Comment: @Dylan changed it to: <?php
    $files = scandir("uploads");
    for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++)
    {
        echo '<script>printJS('/uploads/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>');</script>'
    }
    ?> and didn't work